Repeated datetime in hourly sequence in r using seq()
When creating a sequence of datetimes as suggested here:
Hourly Date Sequence In R
I get repeats that are undetectable with duplicate() or unique().
Specifically, with:
test = seq(as.POSIXct("2004-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2024-06-01 00:00:00"), by="hour")

The result for test[7297] and test[7298] is "2004-10-31 01:00:00 CDT". There are many other repeated datetimes in the sequence.
How do you create a long series of datetimes and not create these duplicates?

When I run your code (in Eastern timezone) and look at those two elements, I see "2004-10-31 01:00:00 EDT" "2004-10-31 01:00:00 EST". You can see the timezone changes from EDT (daylight time) to EST (standard time), and this is the repeated hour when you "fall back".

If you would prefer to not deal with daylight savings time, specify a timezone like UTC that doesn't use it: set tz = 'UTC' in your as.POSIXct() calls.

Ah, yes, I see it now. Thank you!
